# Uniquely New York curses

Tags: phrase-requests, dialects, offensive-language

This is kind-of an oddball question but the site rules don't appear to forbid it. If it somehow violates guidelines just let me know and I'll voluntarily take it down.

I'm looking for region-specific curses, ones that can easily pin down the speaker's home territory, in this case New York (the city and surrounding metro area). For example, in much of the "Bible Belt" areas like Kentucky, one of the most well-known examples of a regional curse is "Bless your heart!" It sounds innocuous to an outsider, but coming from a local that is about as harsh as you'll get.

So what's a good equivalent in the NYC area? Something that would easily identify the speaker as a "New Yorker".

Comment: I’m a lifelong, native NYCer. Born and raised in Manhattan, and have lived all my life on the island (and a few years in neighboring Jersey City). And I have a relatively foul mouth. To my knowledge, in the modern day, there are no uniquely NYC curses. Just relatively heavier (and sometimes more creative) use of standard four-letter words. But I’ll be happy to weigh in on anyone else’s answer in case a word I think is “standard” actually turns out to be NYC-specific. I wouldn’t fall into the trap of trying to use dated terms from specific communities, like “goombah” etc.

Comment: ***Cor blimey**!* I'd have thought that as one of the world's great cities, New York would be so cosmopolitan that you couldn't really identify the inhabitants by their use of historically localised dialectal forms. And no - I've never lived in London, myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There was a UK cartoon when I was a kid, called “Danger Mouse”. A sort of cartoon parody on James Bond. The protagonist’s sidekick was a cowardly mole named Penfold, and he talked like that in a very exaggerated fashion. Used to say “crikey” and “cheese and carrots!”. I loved it. Some other characters had parodic accents from other areas as well; Scottish, Texan, etc.

Comment: Relevant: ["Dropping the F-bomb"](https://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/dropping-the-f-bomb) from The New Yorker.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a completely foolproof method, but if you need to identify a New Yorker by 'curse words', (sans characteristic accent) the sprinkling of Yiddish (*schmuck*, *putz*, etc.) in an unflattering rant is a clue.

Comment: Hah, I was just thinking that! Here's a fun, slightly relevant link: https://groupthink.kinja.com/a-guide-to-swearing-in-yiddish-483890863